# Access to WindowsFormsParkingWindow?

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

I've been trying to obtain text from a panel that's part of a third-party application; I have the process ID. To do this, I've gone through the usual EnumProcessModulesEx / GetModuleBaseName / EnumWindows / EnumChildWindows steps. This code works when the panel is shown, but when it's hidden, the panel is no longer seen by my code or Spy++. I'd figured the panel must be destroyed and re-created as the user hides and shows the panel, but it turns out that the HWND of the panel is valid in both situations (GetWindow, GetTitle, etc. all return without errors, and with the same information, so the handle hasn't been re-used); the only difference is that its parent is different. When I trace the parent chain back to the root, the topmost parent's title is WindowsFormsParkingWindow, same process ID. I searched for WindowsFormsParkingWindow, and it seems to be a temporary place to "park" a HWND when you don't need it, so you won't have to re-create the window and its children. Does anyone know of an API for traversing the WindowsFormsParkingWindow hierarchy, or some other way of getting to this panel? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear. This is a 3rd party application, I have no control over what they're doing with their windows, and I don't want to manipulate/modify their windows, just get the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowsFormsParkingWindow is a message-only window.

You can enumerate message-only windows by calling [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the special window handle HWND_MESSAGE.

Comment: I found an example of what you're describing [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?208587-About-message-only-windows), I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

Based on information from this blog:

[Flashback: Windows Forms Parking Window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2007/06/20/flashback-windows-forms-parking-window.aspx)

The Parking Window is just a generic parent window used for arbitrarily re-parenting child windows onto during parent window recreations.  There is no API to query information from the Packing Window itself, such as the original parent window for any given parked child window.  Only the original parent/control knows which child HWND(s) have been parked so they can be retrieved when needed.

The best you are likely to accomplish is to detect when the panel is visible, remember that HWND, and then just use that HWND when needed, even when the panel is not visible.  Or at least enumerate the WindowsFormsParkingWindow to check if that HWWND is still a child of it, etc.  But if the panel is losing its text while parked, then you are likely to be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks; how do I get the handle for WindowsFormsParkingWindow? It doesn't seem to show up in EnumWindows().